# Obtener subcategoria de un post en especifico en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando obtener el nombre y id de una subcategoria de un post en especifico (pasandole el post_id).

Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Como referencia cree una categoria llamada blog, dentro de ella tendre subcategorias, la idea es que al crear una nueva entrada y seleccione la subcategoria esta se pueda dibujar en mi html.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo, por si alguien mas lo esta buscando se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php query_posts('cat=15'); ?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    $cat_name = 'category';
                    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $cat_name );
                    foreach($categories as $category) {
                        if($category->parent){
                            $subcategoria = $category->name;
                        }
                    }  
                ?>

//Codigo aqui

<?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```